# jdbc basic what reference am I missing

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

Newbie: I am just trying to get the example code shown below to work. I am using Linux Ubuntu 12.04, NetBeans 7.2. The article link is here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html

I am getting "Cannot find symbol" error for the red squiggly lines shown below. All I'm trying to do is get that small snippet of code that is highlighted below to run, that's it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the errors in the IDE ?  It looks like you forgot to import a namespace.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical way of explaining why things don't work. Be specific. Quote any error code or message or warning you get.

Comment: i don't know what i need to import

Comment: "the source code is worth a thousand screenshots".

Comment: i have a link to the article in OP

Comment: Please post text for text. You also need to actually say what is/isn't working.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add import statements to your Java program to import required classes in your Java code.Import JDBC Packages like this;

```
     import java.sql.*;
```

Comment: That worked. Almost there! I'm getting the infamous "Driver not found". If you look at the second image in OP that was a sample app I generated in NetBeans and it works (New Project/Sample/NetBeansModule/CRUD Example). So I looked at that connection string. What am I missing?

Comment: @Rod Add java derby driver jar on your classpath.I think netbeans has java derby driver.

Answer (score 0):

As it say on the website, that code is a fragment, it will not run on it's own because some classes being used there have not been defined elsewhere.

You will need all the classes (make sure you have imports and classpath right) for it to work.

Example:

```
*Connection* con = (...)
```

Where is the Connection class defined?